How to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^3(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}) d x$?
The substitution $x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}-x$ is always helpful for evaluating integral consisting of polynomials and trigonometric function.
$$I_0=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}) d x = 
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x \Rightarrow 
I_0 =0$$
However, when I multiply the integrand by $x$ and use the same substitution, I fails to evaluate $$I_1= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}) d x$$ since
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x+I_1\end{aligned}
$$
in which $I_1$ on both sides cancel each other.
Then I started to investigate $I_1$ by letting $t=\tan x$ and get
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1& =\int_0^{\infty} \tan ^{-1} t\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) \frac{d t}{1+t^2} \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t-1}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+t^2\right)} \tan ^{-1} t d t \\
& =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2-1}{1+t^4} \tan ^{-1} (t^2) d t \text {, where } t \mapsto t^2\\&=2J(1)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $J(a)= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2-1}{1+t^4} \tan ^{-1} (at^2) d t .$
Differentiating $J(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J^{\prime}(a)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2\left(t^2-1\right)}{\left(1+t^4\right)\left(1+a^2 t^4\right)} d t \\
& = \frac{1}{a^2-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2+1}{1+t^4} d t-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+a^2 t^2}{1+a^2 t^4} d t\right]\\
& =\frac{1}{a^2-1}\left[\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi(a+1)}{2\sqrt{2a}}\right] \\
& =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\left(a^2-1\right)}\left(1-\frac{a+1}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(1) & =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{a^2-1}\left(1-\frac{a+1}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right) d a \\
& =\frac{\pi\ln 2}{2\sqrt 2} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$\boxed{I_1=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{2}  }$$
Putting $x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}-x$ again to $I_2$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2 & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x-\pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(\sqrt{\cot x} -\sqrt{\tan x}) -I_2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging gives
$$\boxed{I_2 =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}) d x =\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi \ln 2}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi^2 \ln 2}{2 \sqrt{2}}}$$
To continue, I am stuck by the cancelling of $I_3$ in the equation $$
\begin{aligned}
I_3 & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^3(\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}) d x \\
& =\frac{3 \pi^2}{4} I_1-\frac{3 \pi}{2} I_2+I_3
\end{aligned}
$$
which reveals that it is harder to find $I_{2n-1}$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$.
My question:
How to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^3(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}) d x$?
Your comments and solutions are highly appreciated.

Are you sure it converges for every $n$

I guess so.  Thank you for your reminder.

Substituting $x\to x+\frac\pi4$ instead, exploiting symmetry, and then $x\to\arctan x$ produces two Ahmed-like integrals,$$I_3=\frac{3\pi^2}4\int_0^1\frac{x\arctan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x^2)},dx+4\int_0^1\frac{x\arctan^3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x^2)},dx$$The first integral I'm almost certain has been posted before... maybe not, Approach0 isn't much help... or should at least be amenable to methods used for similar integrals. That cubed arctan doesn't seem so friendly

Another similar problem

Thank you very much for your suggestion and reference.
